# Custom Rewrite rule to match anything not already matched by WordPress

Tags: rewrite-rules

I have these slugs on my website

```
http://www.domain.com/about (standard WP page)
http://www.domain.com/custom-slug (not a WP page, post or custom post type)
```

I'm trying to develop a rewrite rule to match the latter scenario, to redirect them to my custom plugin so I can render content for them.
My rewrite rule looks like this

```
add_rewrite_rule('^(.*)/?', 'index.php?pagename=special-page&id=$matches[1]', 'bottom');
```

By setting it to `'bottom'` it kicks in after all other WordPress rewrite rules, and so won't get processed - WordPress will send a request for `/custom-slug` to the 404 page.

If I set the rewrite rule to `'top'` then every page on WordPress will be matched. That would be ok if my rewrite rule executed and it checked in a custom database table to see if `/custom-slug` is a valid slug in my custom system. If it does then render content for it. If it doesn't to have WordPress continue on trying to make a match for it (redirect `/about` to the actual about page on the site)

Normally rewrite rules are more straightforward where you match a specific keyword in the URL following by a string after it, but that won't work for me - all slugs will look the same.

Any ideas on how best to accomplish this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't do that with a rewrite rule, the regular page rule already matches, but you can intercept the data that's extracted from that rule before it gets transformed into a query.

We do that by hooking the `parse_request` action, where we can check for a custom slug, and modify the request object directly. I recommend you `var_dump($query)` and have a look at the whole object for different kinds of requests. See comments in code.

```
add_action( 'parse_request', 'wpd_check_for_my_custom_slug' );
function wpd_check_for_my_custom_slug( $query ) {
    if( isset( $query->query_vars['pagename'] ) ){
        // check if the slug matches some custom content
        // replace this with your query code
        if( 'my-custom-slug' == $query->query_vars['pagename'] ){
            // the request is for a custom slug
            // store the originally requested slug
            $query->query_vars['my_special_var'] = $query->query_vars['pagename'];
            // and load a placeholder page
            $query->query_vars['pagename'] = 'placeholder-page';
        }
    }
}
```

Note that if your permalink structure is just `%postname%`, the slug will be in `name`, not `pagename`. You will then also have to `unset` `name` after.

If you plan to load a theme file at the end of this process, I suggest using a placeholder page of the `page` post type for these requests. WordPress expects some kind of post object to exist for a template to successfully render. You can filter and override all of the titles, content, etc..

If you plan on outputting something completely custom, you could load that and just `exit` here.

Comment: Excellent! I had not considered the parse_request action - very powerful and exactly what I need. Thank you for the detailed answer.